# How to put Java objects back into SQL database using ORMLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ormlite

I take entries from SQLite database using ORMLite:

```
OrmliteDatabaseHelper openDatabaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this,
            OrmliteDatabaseHelper.class);
    Dao<Card, Long> cardDao = openDatabaseHelper.getDao();
    QueryBuilder<Card, Long> qb = cardDao.queryBuilder();
    Where where = qb.where();
    dictionary == StartovayaAktivnost.Dict.BASIC)  where.between(Card.ID_FIELD_NAME, "1", "1000");
    PreparedQuery<Card> preparedQuery = qb.prepare();
    List<Card> cardsList = qb.prepare();
```

Now it's all inside list (cardsList), my program work with it, change some fields, remove and add new entries, etc. And then I need to save this changes in db. How can I push Java list back to database with ORMLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `callBatchTasks` for bulk processing.

Try the below code

```
cardDao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        for (Card card : cardsList) {
            cardDao.update(card);
        }
    }
});
```